# display specific values form sorted array

Tags: arrays

this is my sorted array

```
$sortedArray = array($value_one_fin,$value_two_fin,$value_three_fin,$value_four_fin,$value_five_fin,$value_six_fin,$value_seven_fin,$value_eight_fin,$value_nine_fin,$value_ten_fin,$value_eleven_fin,$value_twelve_fin,$value_thirteen_fin,$value_fourteen_fin,$value_fifteen_fin,$value_sixteen_fin,$value_seventeen_fin,$value_eighteen_fin,$value_nineteen_fin,$value_twenty_fin,$value_twentyone_fin,$value_twentytwo_fin,$value_twentythree_fin,$value_twentyfour_fin); 

$result=findClosest($sortedArray,$num1);
```

this is the variable where i store my entered number

```
$num1
```

what i want to do is to display values from sorted array  in the manner ***Buy at / above: 102.51   Targets: 105,107.58,110.19,112.83
Stoploss : 100***

in the above example i have entered 100 as $num1. as per calc the $result is also 100 so it has to display next greater closest number which is 102.51 and in stop loss it shuld display next smaller closest number

**CONDITION**

1>if entered number $num1 is greater than $result then display the next greater closest number from sorted array

2>if entered number $num1 is equal to $result then display the next greater closest number from sorted array

pls help me with this how can i do this im doing this

```
Buy At/Above ";if ($num1>$result) {echo "$result ";}if ($num1=$result) {echo "$result ";}if ($num1<$result) {echo "$result ";}echo "for Targets"; if ($result<$value_one_fin){echo " $value_one_fin,";} 
              if ($result<$value_two_fin){echo " $value_two_fin,";} 
              if ($result<$value_three_fin){echo " $value_three_fin,";} 
              if ($result<$value_four_fin){echo " $value_four_fin,";} 
              if ($result<$value_five_fin){echo " $value_five_fin,";} 
              if ($result<$value_six_fin){echo " $value_six_fin,";} 
              if ($result<$value_seven_fin){echo " $value_seven_fin,";} 
              if ($result<$value_eight_fin){echo " $value_eight_fin,";} 
              if ($result<$value_nine_fin){echo " $value_nine_fin,";} 
              if ($result<$value_ten_fin){echo " $value_ten_fin,";} 
              if ($result<$value_eleven_fin){echo " $value_eleven_fin,";} 
              if ($result<$value_twelve_fin){echo " $value_twelve_fin,";} 
              if ($result<$value_thirteen_fin){echo " $value_thirteen_fin,";} 
              if ($result<$value_fourteen_fin){echo " $value_fourteen_fin,";} 
              if ($result<$value_fifteen_fin){echo " $value_fifteen_fin,";} 
              if ($result<$value_sixteen_fin){echo " $value_sixteen_fin,";} 
              if ($result<$value_seventeen_fin){echo " $value_seventeen_fin,";} 
              if ($result<$value_eighteen_fin){echo " $value_eighteen_fin,";} 
              if ($result<$value_nineteen_fin){echo " $value_nineteen_fin,";} 
              if ($result<$value_twenty_fin){echo " $value_twenty_fin,";} 
              if ($result<$value_twentyone_fin){echo " $value_twentyone_fin,";} 
              if ($result<$value_twentytwo_fin){echo " $value_twentytwo_fin,";} 
              if ($result<$value_twentythree_fin){echo " $value_twentythree_fin,";} 
              if ($result<$value_twentyfour_fin){echo " $value_twentyfour_fin";}
```

but its not working and also how to display STOP LOSS

Comment: I didn't understand what you were doing in your previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12946827/display-results-in-php-for-gann-square-of-nine and I'm still not too sure about it. Your conditions 1 and 2 do the same thing, they both display the next greater closest number. What's the difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologies if I've misunderstood the question - I'm not 100% clear what you're trying to achieve, but I'll try to be helpful.

It looks as though your array is sorted smallest to largest. So to find the first value greater than or equal to $num1, simply loop through your array from beginning to end, and stop when you find a value >= $num1 e.g.

```
function findClosest($sortedArray, $num1) {
  foreach ($sortedArray as $value) {
    if ($value >= $num1) {
      return $value;
    }
  }
}
```

To find the closest number less than or equal to $num1, loop through the array from the end to the beginning e.g.

```
function findClosestLessThanOrEqual($sortedArray, $num1) {
  for ($i = sizeOf($sortedArray) - 1; $i >= 0; $i--) {
    if ($sortedArray[$i] <= $num1) {
      return $sortedArray[$i];
    }
  }
}
```

There are faster ways to search a large array, but if your array only contains 24 values I think that's the simplest way.

Comment: xSphere thanks u where such a help... now how do i get first 5 items which are greater than the entered value ie $num1 and  first 5 items which are less than the entered value ie $num1

Answer (score 0):

Just needs a slight tweak to get the first 5 items >= $num1:

```
function find5Closest($sortedArray, $num1) {
  for ($i = 0; $i < sizeOf($sortedArray); $i++) {
    if ($sortedArray[$i] >= $num1) {
      return array_slice($sortedArray, $i, 5);
    }
  }
}
```

This should return an array up to 5 values. If there are only 3 values >= $num1, then it will only return 3 values; if no values are >= $num1 it will return an empty array.

Similarly:

```
function find5ClosestLessThanOrEqual($sortedArray, $num1) {
  for ($i = sizeOf($sortedArray) - 1; $i >= 0; $i--) {
    if ($sortedArray[$i] <= $num1) {
      return array_slice($sortedArray, min(0, $i-4), 5);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: when im trying to print find5closest and find5closestlessthanor equal its giving me Array as output.

Comment: Yes, if you want it to return 5 values you need it to return an array. When printing the results you need to loop through the array (easiest way is to use foreach)